# C++ default arguments in function overload evaluated once or each time?

Tags: c++, overloading, default-arguments

I have a question on defaults for overload functions in an object.

If I have a function signature as follows will the default value be evaluated only once or each time?

```
class X
{
  public:
  f(const RWDate& d=RWDate::now());
}

// when calling f() do I get the current time each time?
X z;
z.f();

// is the default value of d recaculated in the function call?
z.f();
```

Comment: There is no function overload anywhere here…

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The default arguments are substituted at the call site, so `z.f()` is transformed into

```
z.f(RWDate::now())
```

Thus, the default argument is evaluated each time the function is called and the default argument is used.